# Why are not outputs the same after re-executing my multithreading code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

When I execute the following code, after every re-compile and re-execute,  the answers(outputs) are not the same. What is a reason for it?

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
//#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << tid << endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   int i;
   for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, 
                          PrintHello, (void *)i);
      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

g++ test.cpp -o test -lpthread
./test

Output1:

```
main() : creating thread, 0
main() : creating thread, 1
main() : creating thread, 2
Hello World! Thread ID, 0
main() : creating thread, 3
Hello World! Thread ID, 1
Hello World! Thread ID, 2
main() : creating thread, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 3
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
```

g++ test.cpp -o test -lpthread
./test

Output2:

```
main() : creating thread, 0
main() : creating thread, 1
main() : creating thread, 2
main() : creating thread, 3
Hello World! Thread ID, 0
main() : creating thread, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 3
Hello World! Thread ID, 2
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your threads aren't synchronized, the execution order is not precisely determined, and depends on your execution context, such as what other processes are running at the same time, etc, which will probably be different each time you run your program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how  can I determine the order of executions?

Comment: @Code in advance? You can't, really. In retrospect, you can see it there. In `Output1` it's 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and in `Output2` 0, 3, 2, 4, 1.

Comment: You can use synchronization primitives such as `pthread_mutex_lock()`, `pthread_cond_wait()` and the like to control this. See https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes and https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables for more details

Comment: Yes, then it needs the concepts of OS course. However when i have get it code of http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm, I thought the order must be : main():0,1,2,3, and   ID: 0,1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 0):

yes. I have used of
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); and pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS     5
pthread_mutex_t   mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   //sleep(1);

 cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << tid << endl;

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   int i;
//pthread_attr_t attr;
//pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   //pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
   for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;

      rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)i);

//sleep(0.5);
      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

and my outputs is always:

```
main() : creating thread, 0
Hello World! Thread ID, 0
main() : creating thread, 1
Hello World! Thread ID, 1
main() : creating thread, 2
Hello World! Thread ID, 2
main() : creating thread, 3
Hello World! Thread ID, 3
main() : creating thread, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
```